# Future with will or present continuous

Tags: present-continuous, future

I would like to know if I using a present continous would be correct in this example:
"Are you going home now? In that case, I.....with you".

The book key just gives "Will leave" as correct.
"In that case, I am leaving with you" sounds natural to me but it is true that it is not something arranged beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find "I will leave with you" particularly natural, but suppose we change it to

> Are you going to the cafeteria for lunch? In that case, I'll go with you.

The speaker uses "I will go" because they have just decided to go now. As you say, "I'm going" is much less likely because the continuous tense usually implies an existing arrangement.